# gem install error sass-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile

I want to install an old version of `sass-rails` gem. But i am getting this error and my css is not working on my project, check it:

In Gemfile

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier',     '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'watchr'
end
```

and when I run this command `bundle install` then I got this error:

```
$ bundle install
Your Gemfile lists the gem sass-rails (~> 3.2.3) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
Your Gemfile lists the gem coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
Your Gemfile lists the gem uglifier (>= 1.0.3) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
```

Please Help me to sort out this..

Comment: This is just a warning, not an error. The gems are (probably, as far as we can tell) being installed correctly and any problems with CSS are (probably) not due to this warning. As the warning says: your Gemfile lists the same gem multiple times. If you don't understand why or where, please post your complete Gemfile and the complete output of `bundle install`.

Comment: So, this is all Gemfile? no `source 'https://rubygems.org'` at the start or anything else?